# Flutter TextFieled , The hint and cursor is in the bottom of the text filed even with specifying that the verticalTextAlign as Center

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

```dart
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
 class TextFiledMessageSend extends StatelessWidget {
 const TextFiledMessageSend({super.key});
 
   @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return TextField(
      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: "Type your message ",
        // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        prefixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions, size: 22)),
      ),
    );
}
```

I want that the hint Text and the cursor is in the center horizontal as wel as the prefixIcon,suffixIcon is in the center :

[Here is the image of the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKXcm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by removing the size of the prefixIcon and applying a contentPadding :

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Type your message',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
    prefixIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions)),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextField` is expanding.

So, set [`isDense`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/isDense.html) to `true` on the `InputDecoration` and remove `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center`:

```dart
TextField(
        // textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,<-- Remove this
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true, // <-- Added this
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: "Type your message ",
          // contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          prefixIcon: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions, size: 22)),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: When I change isDense to true it is on the top not center

Comment: @OtmaneBachri so maybe also add `textAlignVertical` in addition to `isdense`